# Conflicts between mingw SDL2 and mingw on Linux cross compiling for Windows

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, cross-compiling, sdl-2

I have a problem with cross-compiling SDL2 app to Win32. I did download the `mingw-w64` package with the headers, the `mingw-w64-sdl2` aur package and `mingw-w64-luajit` for the app, cmake doesn't detect their paths, so I made a toolchain file with their paths. Cmake started working.

Now make, then a bunch of conflicts between mingw files (`intrin.h`, `stdlib.h`) and SDL2 files (`SDL_cpuinfo.h`, `SDL_stdinc.h`) like:

```
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/neko8.dir/src/api.cpp.obj
In file included from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:38,
                 from /home/pibeplayer/neko8/src/graphics.hpp:4,
                 from /home/pibeplayer/neko8/src/neko.hpp:9,
                 from /home/pibeplayer/neko8/src/api.cpp:3:
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/intrin.h:259:5: error: declaration of ‘int abs(int)’ has a different exception specifier
     __MACHINE(int __cdecl abs(int))
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_stdinc.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_main.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:32,
                 from /home/pibeplayer/neko8/src/graphics.hpp:4,
                 from /home/pibeplayer/neko8/src/neko.hpp:9,
                 from /home/pibeplayer/neko8/src/api.cpp:3:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:722:12: note: from previous declaration ‘int abs(int) noexcept’
 extern int abs (int __x) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__)) __wur;
            ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:38,
                 from /home/pibeplayer/neko8/src/graphics.hpp:4,
                 from /home/pibeplayer/neko8/src/neko.hpp:9,
                 from /home/pibeplayer/neko8/src/api.cpp:3:
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/intrin.h:261:5: error: declaration of ‘long int labs(long int)’ has a different exception specifier
     __MACHINE(long __cdecl labs(long))
```

If someones needs more info, I have a text with my CMake file contents, the toolchains, and the output & errors of cmake. And make in pastebin:
[Pastebin Link](https://pastebin.com/LnrCRgcM). What else am I missing? Any help appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be using /usr/include for header files for cross-compiling. You need to specify a "systeminclude" path that is pointing at your Windows  headers for things like stdlib.h and similar.

Comment: Having the same problem.

Comment: Isn't `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32` is a **sysroot** for your cross-compilation? If so, mark it correspondingly in the toolchain file: `set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/usr/i686-w64-mingw32")`. With that setting, host include directory `/usr/include/` shouldn't be used by the compiler (unless it is explicitly added). Also, this could help CMake to find SDL2 and LuaJIT without hardcoded settings in toolchain. Note, that currently you find ZLIB at `/usr/lib/libz.a`, which is host library. Probably, you need to have mingw ZLIB installation as well.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your response, sure, it helped me a lot, but now I have another error about  `stdlib_s.h`...:
new [Pastebin Link](https://pastebin.com/KQ29wRdf)

Comment: So your code includes `/usr/include` **explicitly**. Check variables you pass to `include_directories` (with `message()` command). Probably, it is ZLIB which is responsible for that (see my previous comment).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, yeah, you were right, adding `GET_DIRECTORY_PROPERTY(output INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
MESSAGE(WARNING ${output})``to CMakeLists.txt gives me:
`/usr/include/SDL2/usr/include/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/home/pibeplayer/neko8/include/home/pibeplayer/neko8/libs/include`, still I don't know what to do, I did install zlib for mingw, the cmake detects the new dir, but the error still persists :(

Comment: According to output, CMake detects **old** dir for ZLIB (`/usr/lib/libz.a`). In toolchain set  [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE.html) and  `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY` variables to `ONLY`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think that's not the problem, because: `Found ZLIB: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libz.dll.a (found version "1.2.11")`
But `/usr/include` get's included automatically, and `/usr/include/SDL2` instead of `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2`, I 'hardfixed' it by modifying the includes_CXX.rsp and it compiles, but it shouldn't be that way...

Comment: Finally solved!
my real problem was on `cmake/modules/findLuaJIT.cmake` & `cmake/modules/findSDL2.cmake.
I added :
```if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows")
    message(STATUS "Windows")
    SET(SDL2_SEARCH_PATHS
    /usr/i686-w64-mingw32
    ${SDL2_PATH}
)
else()
    message(STATUS "Linux")
    SET(SDL2_SEARCH_PATHS
    ~/Library/Frameworks
    /Library/Frameworks
    /usr/local
    /usr
    /sw # Fink
    /opt/local # DarwinPorts
    /opt/csw # Blastwave
    /opt
    ${SDL2_PATH}
)
endif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows")```
and the same adapted to LuaJIT ;)